# How to remove software of unable to find?

Tags: software-installation, software-center, 19.10, filemanager, jack

I'm going to remove the software that is not installed as a package manager from Ubuntu 19.10.

**The software that I'm going to remove, is installed with Ardour software. The installation method is as follows [this](https://ardour.org/first_time_linux.html).**

The software that needs to be removed does not even exist in the snap folder. I've accessed the root folder, but I don't know which one to remove.

The software I am trying to erase is as follows:

- [Jack](https://jackaudio.org/) and [QjackCtl](https://qjackctl.sourceforge.io/)

I tried to find a way to remove the software from the site, but I found nothing. I want to contact them, but I can't see their contact information.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate how these packages were installed in the first place.

Comment: what root folder is this `/usr/bin/` or ... ?

Comment: @Graham Thank you for your feedback. I updated.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I meant /usr/bin.

Comment: then use the instructions found there to uninstall

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen There are instructions for Ardour, but there are no instructions for other software.

Comment: The other being `QjackCtl` I suppose?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Yes, but it's clear that the Jack software isn't completely removed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102012/discussion-between-george-udosen-and-bakuiseok).

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at the two and for:

1. [Jack](https://jackaudio.org/downloads/), there were two options use the `apt-get` or the `tar ball` to install. In the case of the latter you simply remove it from the installation folder using `sudo rm -f /path/to/executable` and for the former use the command `sudo apt-get purge jack`,
2. For the [QjacCtl](https://qjackctl.sourceforge.io/) you installed using `[sudo] make install` from a directory so go there and run `[sudo] make uninstall` to remove it from where it was installed. This option should be used as it will locate all the connected files and remove them if you manually remove using `sudo rm -rf` then you have to find any such files and remove them yourself.

Comment: I didn't install it using the package manager. And I can't find the path to the QjackCtl.

Comment: Where did you download the QjackCtl to on your system? @bakuiseok

Comment: I don't know that. To be honestly, It's biggest problem. This software was installed automatically when I installed the Ardour.

Comment: Then just uninstall the Ardour and it should remove every installed program. I think the instructions on that page are sufficient to do this @bakuiseok